# SQL: Cross-platform generation of N-digit unique identifier (SQL Server, Snowflake, etc.)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have two databases/warehouses on two different platforms--Microsoft SQL Server and Snowflake (cloud data warehouse).

Across both, customers are identified via a unique `AccountId` (integer) and `Uuid` (32 character).

For a particular use case, we need to take one of these unique values (say, the `AccountId` for instance), pass it into a system function, and generate **a unique 20-character identifier** (it can't be longer/shorter).

This function needs to exist in both systems. (e.g. `select sys.myfn(1234)` returns the same in each)

I am aware that Snowflake has functions like `sha1()`: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sha1.html

Which are equivalent to `HASHBYTES()` in SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

How do I take the output from either and truncate it down to 20 characters and maintain uniqueness?

Comment: You can't truncate a hashed value and expect it to still be unique.  The only way you could do this would be to come up with your own algorithm that works on both Snowflake and SQL Server and guarantee's uniqueness.  Is there a reason that the identifier has to be 20 characters?

Comment: If you have a unique AccountId, you don't need to use the UUID at all. Can you simply left pad zeros on the AccountId to get to 20 digits?

Comment: why do you need to truncate anything? hashing algorithms produce a consistently sized output. Byte length itself is efficient when persisting the output as binary instead of char. As the comments above suggest, if you attempt to truncate anything you'll lose that function what these hashing algorithms are renowned for: uniqueness.

Comment: @MikeWalton has to be 20-characters because output ultimately ends up with a .gov agency and they will only accept that length.

Comment: @GregPavlik I thought about just left-padding, but upstream mgmt doesn't want to expose numeric account id's in any way

Answer (score -1):

A UUID is a 128bit value (with a few bits reserved for version information). If you run that through a hash function, perform a base64 encoding of the hash, and then truncate to 20 characters, you still get 20 * 6 = 120 bits of range. The chance of collision is still in in the life-of-the-universe ballpark.

(Note: If you choose to base64 encode the UUID directly, truncation may yield collisions for sequentially assigned UUIDs.)

The integer value can be similarly encoded with little chance of collision with the UUID based values.

If you can find equivalent usable base64 wncoding implementations on both platforms, I think you will be on your way to a solution.